# Output window stuck on black screen

Tags: c, recursion, tail-recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static int x;
    if(x == 10)
    printf("\n thanks...");
    x++;
    return (x=main());
}
```

On running the program it gets stuck on the output:

thanks...

What is the problem here?

Comment: Are you for some reason opposed to the use of additional functions? Why are you calling `main` recursively, instead of factoring the logic out into a separate function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no terminating condition for this recursion. Hence leads you to  - a -  [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499253/output-window-stuck-on-black-screen/5499265#5499265).

Perhaps this is what you wanted to try:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    static int x;

if(x==10)
{
    printf("\n thanks...");
    return 0;  // --> Missing
}
x++;
return (x=main());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I executed the program and it actually crashes as expected.
The recursion call goes on non stop and when stack segment has no more space this happens.

The reason you are not getting crash is due to optimization settings of your compiler. Which detects tail recursion and converts them to non to infinite loop.